# Is it possible to use ecoinvent uncertanties in a foreground inventory?

Tags: brightway

I'm having trouble when importing an inventory, as a database. I have an excel inventory containing amounts, locations and ecoinvent flows. However I intend to run a MC simulation with background uncertainty. Is there a way to get the uncertainty parameters to my inventory or to link it with ecoinvent using the match database or apply_strategies methods? I haven't found much about it in the documentation.
When I try:

```
    bd.projects.migrate_project_25
    fp = <'inventory_path'>
    enzymes = bi.ExcelImporter(fp)
    enzymes.match_database("ecoinvent 3.8 cutoff", fields=('name','unit','location','uncertainty type','scale'))
    enzymes.match_database("biosphere3", fields=('name','unit','uncertainty type','loc','scale'))
    enzymes.apply_strategies()
    enzymes.statistics()
    enzymes.write_database()
```

I get unlinked exchanges, and if I try without the uncertainty parameter in the match_database function, I get no unlinked exchanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your question!

When you run the `match_database` function, you are trying to match specific parameters in two databases where you could have differences that you want to either ignore or keep. So, for example:

```py
a = {'foo': True, 'bar': False}
b = {'foo': True, 'bar': True}
```

If I wanted to treat `a` and `b` as the same thing, I could do:

```py
def match_objects(first: dict, second: dict, fields: [str]) -> bool:
    return all(first.get(field) == second.get(field) for field in fields)

match_objects(a, b, ['foo'])
>>> True
```

However, if I wanted them to not match, I could run:

```py
match_objects(a, b, ['foo', 'bar'])
>>> False
```

This is exactly what `match_database` does. You only need to put in the fields you want to use for matching, not the fields you will eventually use for calculations or other purposes. Probably that is just `name` and `unit` in your example.

Brightway will write all the fields when writing the database, and you will be able to use them later on.